# Rails Routes - slash character vs hash character

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, syntax, routes, rails-routing

In urls and rails routing, what is the difference between using a slash character vs a pound sign (hash sign) character?

These work

```
get "/static_pages/about"
get 'about', to: 'static_pages#about', as: :about
```

These don't

```
get "/static_pages#about"
get 'about', to: 'static_pages/about', as: :about
get 'about', to: '/static_pages#about', as: :about
```

What code controls this behavior, and what is the deeper reason behind it?

ANSWER:

(The two people answered it very well, and I had trouble choosing which one to mark as the accepted answer. I wish to state my understanding of the answer in a different way that might help people.)

Once you use the / symbol, the string gets recognized as a url string appended to the base url. So a '#' character will be interpreted as part of the url, and urls don't like to take '#' characters.

In the case of not using a / character, the first word is recognized somehow as a controller name, which you follow up with a '#' and an action name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `#` in `to: 'static_pages#about'` means `about` action of `static_pages_controller`.  The syntax is `controller#action`.

When you define `get "/static_pages#about"`, `static_pages#about` becomes the controller for the route i.e. the `#` is only a character literal and `#about` does not mean `about` action. You should get a `missing :controller` error if `static_pages#about` controller does not exist.

The following route definition gives you `/about` path which maps to `static_pages/about` controller's `about` action, where `static_pages` could either be a namespace or a scope.

```
get 'about', to: 'static_pages/about', as: :about
```

The following route is invalid and should throw an error due to the leading slash `/` in `to` option.

```
get 'about', to: '/static_pages#about', as: :about
```

Comment: What does the word "as:" do?

Comment: @Richard, it lets you specify name for the route. In the above examples `as: :about` lets you use `about_path` and `about_url` helpers.

Answer (score 5):

In ruby, the hash symbol generally precedes the name of a instance method of a class. See the left sidebar of the page of the Array class documentation (http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html).

`get "/static_pages#about"` doesn't work because `#about` is not part of the url.

`get 'about', to: 'static_pages/about', as: :about` doesn't work because `/about` doesn't indicate which controller method should be called.

`get 'about', to: '/static_pages#about', as: :about` doesn't work because of the preceding slash before static_pages.