# Rails 4 - Hash in route gets rendered wrongly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I have this line of code in routes.rb

```
get 'products#:id' => 'products#index', as: :products_hash
```

It works, but the problem is that the hash symbol (#) gets rendered as %23.

```
http://localhost:3000/products%2368
```

This is what it should be:

```
http://localhost:3000/products#68
```

How can I achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: Have you read this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21372675/rails-routes-slash-character-vs-hash-character

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't really help haha

Comment: I have to ask. Why do you want to use `http://localhost:3000/products#68` instead of `http://localhost:3000/products/68`?

Comment: Yeah, I'm curious about that too. =)

Comment: Because I don't want the user to use the show action, but rather scroll to the product with id 68 in the index :)

Comment: And what about this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2069190/906511

You could have the `/products/68` and in the show action redirect to index with the anchor

Comment: I believe you should specify this manually in an `anchor` key of a `link_to` helper. It's probably impossible to specify it in routes, because routes are mostly designed to parse and select a path - and the part after a # is not part of the path. And by impossible I mean you'd need to modify rails' methods to make it work. Write a helper maybe.

Comment: You don't want this - the browser does not send what follows the # to the server at all

Comment: This seems to work, any better ideas?:

`private`
`def switches_hash_path(switch)`
`return switches_path(:anchor => switch.id)`
`end`

Answer (score 0):

**Rails**

I feel you're missing the point of [Rails' routing system](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html), which is that you are meant to construct it around objects (hence why you call `resources :controller` etc).

Although I don't understand why you're defining the route you are, I'll give you some ideas. There is a ["wildcard"](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing-and-wildcard-segments) setting for your routes in Rails, which allows you to define & pass parameters to your application out of the scope of the typical "CRUD" based applications:

```
#config/routes.rb
get 'products#*id' => 'products#index', as: :products_hash
```

This will give you the ability to send requests to the following route:

```
<%= link_to "Product", products_hash_path("68") %>
```

You'd then be able to call the param in the controller:

```
#app/controllers/products_controller.rb
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
   def index
      id = params[:id]
   end
end
```